# Ubuntu 14.04 can't login / No sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, login, lts

1. can't log in

this question may be a duplicate but I didn't found a answer to my problem in the other threads.

When I try to login at the typical login screen the screen just "reloads".
I'm 100% sure that I type in the right password, because if I type in a wrong password there's a red writing saying "wrong password".
Also launching a guest session works.

In another thread someone demanded the OP the upload the Xorg.0.log so I did too if it's helpful in any way: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9194342/

2. No sound

While testing the guest session I realized that I don't have any sound.
There's only a "Dummy Output" under sound outputs.
The sound card is a Realtek onboard card.

While testing around with Ubuntu there certainly will be other problems / question. If so I'll post them here.

Greetings

Comment: Have you recently installed/unisntalled the AMD proprietary fglrx drivers, if so how, and what graphics are you using? (use `lspci -k`).

Comment: @Wilf No I haven't. How do I install them?

Comment: zergcheese, please, one question only. @Wilf, if he or she is able to start the guest session, I don't think is a problem with the graphic driver.

Comment: zergcheese, for the first one: try to enter with your main account using a virtual console (Ctrl-Alt-F1, your normal user/password. Ctrl-Alt-F7 to go back to your graphical session), and report back. If you can, a file called `.xsession-errors` in your home directory could have some hint. You can even try http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop